# How can I perform jquery ajax to reload my data without refreshing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

My problem is when I inserted or updated a value, this code is not working but the status code in my network shows 200 means its OK

I want to fetch any data inside tbody section, where I fetch all of my data

This is my entire code

This is my HTML code where my table goes here after the page reload

```
        <!-- Table starts -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
                <thead class="table-head">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Birthday</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Mobile #</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Nickname</th>
                        <th>Occupation</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody class="tbody">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Table ends -->
```

This is my code inside my script I am using jquery ajax to perform it.

```
    //view existing data
    function viewData(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                key: 'viewData',
            },
            success: function(response){

                //this is my problem
                $('.tbody').append(response);

                //After I changed the append to html it works OMG!
                //just like this
                $('.tbody').html(response);

                $(".table").DataTable();
            }
        });
    }


//Insert data
    function manageData(key){
        var username = $('#username');
        var password = $('#password');
        var birthday = $('#birthday');
        var age = $('#age');
        var mobileNumber = $('#mobile-number');
        var fullAddress = $('#full-address');
        var gender = $('#gender');
        var nickname = $('#nickname');
        var occupation = $('#occupation');
        var editRowID = $('#editRowID');
        var query = window.location.search;

        if(isNotEmpty(username) && isNotEmpty(password) && isNotEmpty(birthday)
        && isNotEmpty(age) && isNotEmpty(mobileNumber) && isNotEmpty(fullAddress) 
        && isNotEmpty(gender) && isNotEmpty(nickname) && isNotEmpty(occupation)){
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: query + '/Dental-Clinic/admin/server.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {
                    key: key,
                    username: username.val(),
                    password: password.val(),
                    birthday: birthday.val(),
                    age: age.val(),
                    mobileNumber: mobileNumber.val(),
                    fullAddress: fullAddress.val(),
                    gender: gender.val(),
                    nickname: nickname.val(),
                    occupation: occupation.val(),
                    rowID: editRowID.val()
                },
                success: function(response){
                    username.val(""),
                    password.val(""),
                    birthday.val(""),
                    age.val(""),
                    mobileNumber.val(""),
                    fullAddress.val(""),
                    gender.val(""),
                    nickname.val(""),
                    occupation.val(""),        
                    $(".modal").modal('hide');
                    viewData();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And this is my server.php

```
 //view/refresh data when new record has been saved

if(isset($_POST['key'])){
    if($_POST['key'] == 'viewData'){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM patient_table";
        $result = $connection->query($query);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0){
            $response = '';
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $response .='
                    <tr>
                        <td class="d-flex justify-content-between"> <!--To align the button-->
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="edit('.$row["id"].')" id="edit" value="Edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                        </td>
                        <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["password"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["birthday"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["mobile_number"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["full_address"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["nickname"].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row["occupation"].'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
            echo($response);

        } else
            exit('no data');
    }
}


    //Insert data
    $username = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $birthday = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['birthday']);
    $age = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
    $mobileNumber = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['mobileNumber']);
    $fullAddress = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['fullAddress']);
    $gender = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $nickname = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['nickname']);
    $occupation = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['occupation']);
    $rowID = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['rowID']);

    //add new data when manageData('addNew'); btn is clicked
    if($_POST['key'] == 'addNew'){
        $query = "INSERT INTO patient_table (username, password, birthday, age, mobile_number, full_address, gender, nickname, occupation) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$birthday', '$age', '$mobileNumber', '$fullAddress', '$gender', '$nickname', '$occupation')";
        $result = $connection->query($query);
        if ($result) {
            echo '<script>alert("Successfully Inserted");</script>';
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $connection->error;
            exit("Error connecting to the database");
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you not able to see any data in the table after ajax call or you are seeing duplicate datat? just wanted to know what is the exact issue?

Comment: I am able to see the inserted or updated data when I reload the page, and I want to not refresh the page when I inserted or updated any data

Comment: @Jannus Domingo please show us your insert ajax jquery code.

Comment: @KUMAR See the updated code above, the insert in jquery and insert in server.php

Comment: @JannusDomingo please call `viewData();` function after `success:function`.

Comment: @JannusDomingo and let me know what happens??

Comment: where can I put viewData(); @KUMAR

Comment: @JannusDomingo  just after `success:function` see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @KUMAR thank for your consideration. I figured it out whats the problem

Comment: @JannusDomingo what is the problem??

Comment: @JannusDomingo if my answer helps you & solved your problem then please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: its great................

Answer (score 0):

Here i am Suppose that like this you have an insert code:-

**HTML Code:-**

```
<form id="FORM_ID" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert" />
</form>
```

**jQuery Ajax Code:-**

```
<script>
  $("#FORM_ID").submit(function() {
                var name= $("#name").val();
               
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert.php",
                    data: "name=" + name,
                    success: function(data) {
                       function viewData();   // here call your viewData()
                          name.val("");  
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<!-- Table starts -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-hover table-responsive" id="allData">
        <thead class="table-head">
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Mobile #</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Nickname</th>
                <th>Occupation</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody" id="viewdata">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Table ends -->
```

JS

```
function viewData(){
       var html = "<tr>";
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server.php?apicall=fetch_all',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                if(parsedResponse['error']=== false){
                     $.each(parsedResponse['details'],function(index,item){
                        html += "<td>"+item.id+"</td>";
                        html += "<td>"+item.username+"</td>";
                        html += "<td>"+item.password+"</td>";
                        html += "<td>"+item.email+"</td>";
                        html += "<td>"+item.birthday+"</td>";

                        html += '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary edit" id=' + item.id+ '><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete_item" id=' + item.id+ '><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>';
                        html += "</tr>";
                        $("#viewdata").html(html);
                    });
                }
                                    }
            }).done(function (data) {
        $('#allData').DataTable();
    });;
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
   viewData(); 
   $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
            url: 'server.php?apicall=add_new',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                var parseresponse = JSON.parse(response);
                if(response["error"] === false && response["message"] === "success"){
                    alert("success");
                }else{
                    alert("Error");
                }
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#allData').DataTable();
        });
    });
});
```

server.php

```
$response = array();

if (isset($_GET['apicall'])) {
    switch ($_GET['apicall']) {
        case 'fetch_all':
                $details = array();
                $sql= mysqli_query(conn, query); 
                if($sql){
                    while($rec= mysqli_fetch_array($sql) ){
                        array_push($details, $rec);
                    }
                    $response['error'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = 'has data';
                    $response['details'] = $details;
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Error Occured';
                }
            break;
        case 'add_new':
                $username = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
                $password = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
                $birthday = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['birthday']);
                $age = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
                $mobileNumber = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['mobileNumber']);
                $fullAddress = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['fullAddress']);
                $gender = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
                $nickname = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['nickname']);
                $occupation = $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['occupation']);
                $sql= mysqli_query(conn, query); 
                if($sql){
                    $response['error'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = 'success';
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Error Occured';
                }
            break;
        default:
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
            break;
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: thats good to know. BTW you can choose this method too. a bit lengthy but easy

Comment: Oh I will try it later @AsadMehmood :)

Comment: @JannusDomingo Take your time